# exception handling via polymorphism

Tags: .net, wcf, oop

I need a point of view in this design that I am proposing for handling exceptions.

I have a wcf service that throws different types of fault exceptions:

1. throw new FaultException < BusinessRuleViolationFault >(...)
2. throw new FaultException < SomeOtherViolationFault >(...)
3. ...
4. ...

All these fault exception classes implement an interface called IViolationFault, which has a single HandleException method. The implementation of each such method is different depending on the class they are in; so  for example when these exception classes are caught in the client, all I need to do is just call that HandleException() method and it will be taken care of without me having to write an IF condition to differentiate between the types of errors. In BusinessRuleViolationFault's HandleException() method I might just want to show a message on the screen, while in the other one I might want to log it somewhere and trigger some other action as well...

```
catch (FaultException<BusinessRuleViolationFault> ex)
 {
ex.HandleException();
 }
catch (FaultException<SomeOtherViolationFault> ex)
 {
ex.HandleException();
 }
```

Questions

1. Is there any thing wrong in this
   approach?
2. Is there a way I can reduce the
   number of catch blocks and have just
   one catch block take care of all exception types?
3. Is this a good object oriented way to acheive polymorphism while handling exceptions?

**EDIT**

Ive changed the code to inherit from a base class instead of implementing an interface. My BusinessRuleViolationFault class has the HandleException method, but I am not able to get the HandleException method in the client catch block. What am doing wrong? This is how it is thrown in the service

```
BusinessRuleViolationFault bf = new BusinessRuleViolationFault("");
throw new FaultException<BusinessRuleViolationFault>(bf, new FaultReason(new FaultReasonText("Fault reason here")));
```

This is my BusinessRuleViolationFault code

```
[DataContract]
public class BusinessRuleViolationFault : BaseFault
{
    public BusinessRuleViolationFault(string message)
        : base(message)
    {

    }


    [OperationContract]
    public override string HandleException()
    {
        return "BusinessRuleViolationFault executed";
    }
}



[DataContract]
public abstract class BaseFault
{
    public BaseFault(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [OperationContract]
    public abstract string HandleException();
}
```

Do let me have your thoughts on this. Thanks for your time...

Comment: Why are you using generics on the exception? How does it make live easier?

Comment: @Yves M. The question is tagged _wcf_. In WCF using [`FaultException<TDetail>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199.aspx) is the way to implement fault contracts.

Comment: `[OperationContract]` inside a `[DataContract]` is pointless. You really need to read up on WCF basics - sorry.

Comment: yea, I know. Silly of me to even think that. Thanks for your answer anyways. I have marked it a correct cos it brought me closer to what I wanted to achieve. I have still not got an answer in this thread if the way I have acheived it is right and whether my method is the correct OOP way, so I posted another question here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356669/wcf-exception-throwing-and-handling-the-oop-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Correct sample code.

At least with WCF, where this is the way to implement custom faults, there is nothing wrong to do it that way. Although, you loose polymorphism, as you cannot to something like this

```
// Does not work
try
{
}
catch (FaultException<IVoliationFault> ex)
{
  ex.HandleException();
}
```

to catch your FaultExceptions.

You also (obviously) cannot change the base class `System.ServiceModel.FaultException<TDetail>` or even `System.ServiceModel.FaultException` to include any `HandleException()` method.

What you can do is, to work with reflection to extract the `TDetail` of the FaultException, if any, and then work with that:

```
        try
        {
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            var detail = ex.GetDetail<IViolationFault>(); // EDIT: Specify type

            if (detail != null)
            {
                detail.HandleException();
            }
            else
            {
                // Either not a FaultException<TDetail>, or not FaultException<IViolationFault>.
                throw;
            }
        }
...

public static class FaultExceptionExtensions
{
    public static T GetDetail<T>(this FaultException exception)
    {
        if (exception == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("exception");

        Type type = exception.GetType(); // EDIT: use "exception" instead of "ex"
        if (!type.IsGenericType)
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        Type genType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty("Detail", genType);
        Debug.Assert(pi != null, "FaultException<" + genType + ">.Detail property is missing");

        object val = pi.GetValue(exception, null);

        if (!typeof(T).IsInstanceOfType(val))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        return (T)val;
    }

}
```

Comment: this line "var detail = ex.GetDetail() as IViolationFault;" There is no GetDetail method on the object of type FaultException in the catch block. I tried GetType() but got an error saying that it would not convert.. am I missing something? ...thanks.

Comment: @user20358 Please look at the complete answer. I provide a sample implementation as an extension method in the `FaultExceptionExtensions` class.

Comment: thanks. Itried that. Created the FaultExceptionExtensions class in another namespace but got this error "The type arguments for method 'MyExtension.FaultExceptionExtensions.GetDetail<T>(System.ServiceModel.FaultException)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly." .. I am new to this so probably have missed out on something here.. any ideas what cud be wrong?

Comment: ok I got that line above corrected by using "var detail = fex.GetDetail<BaseFault>();" but now I cant get the HandleException method from the detail object!!

Comment: There was an error in the code, as you already discovered. Sorry. I corrected this. However, what do you mean by "can't get the HandleException method"? It works for me (given your original question I didn't completely follow your updates).

Comment: The HandleException method is in the Datacontract class on the service side which is available in the client side thru the service proxy. I dont think the Methods defined will come thru from the service side code into the proxy... is there some other way I can get the method in the datacontract to execute on the client side?

Comment: ok, I solved that problem by creating partial classes of the datacontract class in the proxy on the client side. Is this the right way to go about it? Am I still following OOP principles or breaking some here?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this approach, it is just a normal use of polymorphism.

You can reduce the number of catch blocks by having all your custom exception classes derive from a base exception class instead of just implementing an interface. For example:

```
public abstract class FaultException : Exception
{
    public abstract void HandleException()
}

public class Faultexception<T> : FaultException
{
     public override void HandleException()
     {
      //your code here
     }
}
```

This way you can catch all your exceptions with just the following:

```
catch (FaultException ex) 
{
     ex.HandleException();
}
```

Comment: Im sorry .. I didnt quite understand how this line "public class Faultexception<T> : FaultException" will work with this line "catch (FaultException ex)"  ..how will the catch know which type of exception was thrown?

Comment: Also, how will that one catch block execute the HandleException() method of BusinessRuleViolationFault if the BusinessRuleViolationFault was thrown in the service and how will the same catch block in the client execute the SomeOtherViolationFault's HandleException() method incase that exception was thrown..?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to take a look at the functional approach documented in [this blog post](http://blog.markrendle.net/2011/02/06/ddd9-teaching-jon-skeet-c-and-fun-with-exceptions/) that allows you to make your try/catch logic a little clearer/terse.
eg:

```
TryCatch.Try(() =>
         {
             using (var stream = File.OpenRead(FileTextBox.Text))
             {
                 Trace.WriteLine(stream.Length);
             }
         })
.Catch<FileNotFoundException,
    DirectoryNotFoundException,
    UnauthorizedAccessException>
    (ex =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Fail");
    });
```